# Does a proxy server protect my download habbits from my ISP?

Tags: vpn, proxy, encryption, ssl, bittorrent

If I torrent files and access websites through a proxy server, can my ISP see what I am up too and the websites I'm visiting (SSL and non-SSL)?

Also, would a proxy suffice or would a VPN be more appropriate for my needs?

Comment: yes, in that they can see the traffic to and from the proxy, and if it is unencrypted, the data within that connection. Also note that Bittorrent uses a number of different types of flows, which each must be configured for proxying separately. VPN can be more secure, but the devil's in the details; a Layer4 VPN (SSL tunneled for instance) may leak quite a bit of information about your activities to the ISP.

Comment: So if i want to be protected from my ISP when browsing your saying that a service like TorGuard or PIA would not work? What would you propose?

Comment: all you can do is encrypt the connection, so that they can't tell what is in the connection. the first leg of any given connection is ALWAYs visible to the ISP, even if they can't decipher them. the only questions are, what can they infer from the connection's visible attributes (destination, number of connections, size of data transfered, duration, etc). There are some sophisticated schemes for forcing all traffic over tor (transparent bridging) but tor is not right for all types of network usage (Bittorrent is a no-no), but otherwise extensive leak testing is required.

Comment: ok, so all my isp can see is that I am transferring data to and from a proxy server, but they can see what it is that i am viewing or transferring?

Comment: that depends on your client's configuration. For Torrents, most clients provide encryption capabilities for you to enable. As for your HTTP proxy, make sure you are connecting to the proxy via HTTPS so that they can't just read the packets CONNECT to determine where you are proxying too.

Comment: Thanks for you help, if you wrote that up as an answer for others to find and read easily I would accept it for you

Answer (score 1):

Browsing websites through a non-encrypted proxy is like changing your clothes before robbing a bank. In other words, the ISP is going to be able to see everything still. Now, using a proxy over SSL adds a better layer of protection. This, however, doesn't stop your ISP tracking your torrents. A VPN, on the other hand, will. Most big name VPNs such as Cyberghost will be your best option. [Use DNS Leak Test](https://www.dnsleaktest.com/) to check your true privacy when using a VPN

Comment: Just remember, not all technologies sold as VPNs these days really are. Only a Layer2 VPN can provide real protection from leaks, since it uses a virtual network adapter through which all traffic is forced. Layer4 VPNs provide essentially no leak protection at all.

Comment: The one I mentioned, Cyberghost, creates a virtual network adapter, as do most VPNs I've seen, but fair point